# How to copy whole string literal to clipboard?

Tags: intellij-idea

Suppose I have the following code: `String str = "to-do-list";`

If I double-click anywhere inside of the quotation marks the Intellij selecting nearest word(***to*** or ***do*** or ***list***).

Is there a shortcut to select the whole string literal without manually selecting whole content of the string with the mouse(in case if literal will be too big)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Main menu | Edit | [Extend Selection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html#editor_code_selection) action (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>(<kbd>Cmd</kbd>)+<kbd>W</kbd> default shortcut).